# How to pass python command line argument?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am a python beginner. Trying to pass some command line arguments.
I have used the following codes. But getting errors... transaction_file = argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range.

```
    import itertools
    import re
    from sys import argv


    print ('Computing frequent item sets.')
    transaction_file = argv[1]
    parameter_file = argv[2]
    output_file = argv[3]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks......

Comment: In your cmd, the command to run should be like: python filename.py parameters

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial on CLI arguments in python : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: You should run from terminal

Comment: how are you executing your python file?

Answer (score -1):

Supped of call:

`python aaa.py a1 a2 a3`

sys.argv len 4 -> sys.argv[3] return the value

or

`python aaa.py a1 a2`

sys.argv len 3 -> sys.argv[3] going in error

How you call the script?